# Facebook: Is it possible to show only the user OWN posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I ask for the wall posts of a user and I also get the posts of other people who posted there.

How do I post ONLY the posts of the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In FQL:

```
SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = <uid> AND actor_id = <uid>
```

If both `source_id` and `actor_id` are the same you will get only that user's posts to his own wall. (See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream)

Is that what you are trying to do? What have you got so far?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to do much with this, because I want the wall posts of a particular user - The site owner. And this appears to require a user session...

Comment: Well, yes, your application can only see the stream of a user who has granted read_stream permission. You have to pass an access_token along with your query.
See this tutorial for some examples of getting the session etc: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/